# i m trying to view my edit form. but it gives route missing parameters for update route

Tags: laravel-5

here is my code.
**Editpost.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('update_post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Edit Post</h1>
            <p>Please fill in this form to update the post.</p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $post->id }} ">

        <label for="name"><b>Post Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Post Name" name="name" value="{{ $post->name }}"><br><br>

        <label for="link"><b>Post Link</b></label>
        <input type="url" placeholder="Enter Link" name="url" value="{{ $post->url }}"><br><br>

        <label for="image"><b>Post Image</b></label>
        <input type="file" placeholder="Upload Image" name="image" value="{{ $post->image }}"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">

        {{--
        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="cancelbtn">Sign Up</button>
            <button type="button" class="signupbtn">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        --}}
    </div>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
route::get('admin/show-post/edit-post/{id}','MyController@edit_post')->name('edit_post');

route::post('admin/show-post/edit-post/update-post/{id}','MyController@update_post')->name('update_post');
```

**this error happened**

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: update_post] [URI: admin/show-post/edit-post/update-post/{id}]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\portfolio\resources\views\editpost.blade.php)
>   http://localhost/portfolio/admin/show-post/edit-post/6

Comment: "_Missing required parameters for [Route: update_post] [URI: admin/show-post/edit-post/update-post/{id}]_" seems quite obvious what the error is. Find your usage of `route('update_post')` and add that parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your form action, to pass the id you want to update

```
action="{{ route('update_post', ['id' => $post->id]) }}
```